# Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have been sitting here for the past 5hours trying to figure out what the error might be. I am new to android development so i can't point out what exactly is wrong. I was trying to build my app to apk for testing but I kept on receiving errors and this message kept on coming out every time it runs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined"/>
</resources>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: May be you have to change the minSdkVersion in your gradle file

Comment: @ARP, change it to what?

Comment: Which minSdkVersion are you using?

Comment: @ARP,, I am using 13

Comment: Try a bigger version, for example 16